# Regex for specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to refactor this piece of code:

```
if(!RenamePCTextBox.Text.Any(c => c == '\\' || c == '/' || c == ':' || c == '*' || c == '?' || c == '"' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '|' || c == '.' || c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '~' || c == '!' || c == '@' || c == '#' || c == '$' || c == '%' || c == '^' || c == '&' || c == '\'' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '_' || c == '[' || c == ']') && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(RenamePCTextBox.Text))
        {
            LabelCanUsePCName.Content = "You can use this name";
            LabelCanUsePCName.Foreground = Brushes.DarkGreen;
        }
```

I would like to know if there is way to write it in regex expression? I think this code looks realy ugly this way. Or what would be better aproach for this?

I need to disable only characters above, another other character wanna leave for usage (like "-" for example).

Comment: You can use - `^[\w\d-]+$`. Any other special character which you want to use mention it in the square brackets `[]`. Also, share some sample inputs you have with you to test the regex.

Comment: @stud3nt Oh thanks, I'l try that one.

Comment: Sure, take a look at - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rin72H/1). Let me know if it suits your requirement and I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Regex`, you could use

```
var containsInvalidChars = Regex.Matches(RenamePCTextBox.Text,@"[\\\/:\*\?\\""<>|. ,~!@#$%\^&\(\}\{\}_\[\]]")
                                .Cast<Match>()
                                .Any();

if(!containsInvalidChars)
{
  // Your code
}
```

Or

```
var containsInvalidChars = Regex.Matches(str,@"[\\\/:\*\?\\""<>|. ,~!@#$%\^&\(\}\{\}_\[\]]")
                                .Count>0;
```

Alternatively, You could achieve this without Regex by using [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) and [`String.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) For example,

```
var invalidCharacters = new[]{'\\','/',':','*','?','"','<','>','|','.',' ',',','~','!','@','#','$','%','^','&','\'','(',')','{','}','_','[',']'}; 

if(!invalidCharacters.Any(RenamePCTextBox.Text.Contains))
{
   // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
/^[^*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]+$/;
```

The carat inside the [ means allow anything except. Its a negation of an expression.

Also, instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty(RenamePCTextBox.Text)`, u can try `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RenamePCTextBox.Text)`.

`IsNullOrWhiteSpace` deals with the scenario: "    "